# TypeScript error: "argument not assignable to XX type"

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-context

Why does this function:

```
  const { jobData, setJobData } = useJobCreation();

  const handleSkillSelect = (skillKey: string) => {
    const skillIndex = jobData.skillSet.findIndex(
      skill => skill.key === skillKey,
    );
    if (skillIndex !== -1) {
      // Skill is already selected, remove it
      const updatedSkillSet = jobData.skillSet.filter(
        skill => skill.key !== skillKey,
      );
      setJobData((prevJobData: JobCreationType) => ({
        ...prevJobData,
        skillSet: updatedSkillSet,
      }));
    } else {
      // Skill is not selected, add it
      const selectedSkill = filteredSkillsData.find(
        skill => skill.key === skillKey,
      );
      if (selectedSkill) {
        setJobData((prevJobData: JobCreationType) => ({
          ...prevJobData,
          skillSet: [...prevJobData.skillSet, selectedSkill],
        }));
      }
    }
  };
```

throw this TypeScript error?

```
Argument of type '(prevJobData: JobCreationType) => { skillSet: Skill[]; jobRequirements: string[]; customRequirements: CustomRequirement[]; jobDetails: JobDetails; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JobCreationType'.
```

when the type is defined in a context provider as this:

```
export interface JobCreationType {
  skillSet: Skill[];
  jobRequirements: string[];
  customRequirements: CustomRequirement[];
  jobDetails: JobDetails;
}
```

I've tried `setJobData(prevJobData => ({ ...prevJobData }));` to simplify it. All that does is restate the problem
`Parameter 'prevJobData' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006) Argument of type '(prevJobData: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JobCreationType'.`

I'm expecting the function to update the React Context provider state depending on whether or not the data have changed.

UPDATE: I added the requested `setJobData` state function.

Comment: i dont see where you declare the state setJobData so that we can check the type my guess it is probably null

Comment: @OyinladeDemola I updated with that information.

Comment: You are passing a function to `setJobData` whereas it expects an object of type `JobCreationType`. `setJobData` is defined in `useJobCreation` so it would be nice to see this hook to have insights on how the type of `setJobData` is inferred

Answer (score 1):

I had to rethink how to update the data in a way that would satisfy typescript. The solution:

```
  const handleSkillSelect = (skillKey: string) => {
    const skillIndex = jobData.skillSet.findIndex(
      skill => skill.key === skillKey,
    );

    if (skillIndex !== -1) {
      // Skill is already selected, remove it
      const updatedSkillSet = jobData.skillSet.filter(
        skill => skill.key !== skillKey,
      );
      const updatedJobData = { ...jobData, skillSet: updatedSkillSet };
      setJobData(updatedJobData);
    } else {
      // Skill is not selected, add it
      const selectedSkill = filteredSkillsData.find(
        skill => skill.key === skillKey,
      );
      if (selectedSkill) {
        const updatedJobData = {
          ...jobData,
          skillSet: [...jobData.skillSet, selectedSkill],
        };
        setJobData(updatedJobData);
      }
    }
  };
```

Rather than try to update it within `setJobData`, I needed to update the value and pass the updated variable in to it.